# Ajustar cualquier imagen por el ancho

Tags: c#, android, xml, imagen, xamarin

Me podrian por favor asistir dandome alguna idea de lograr el resultado de la foto 1 con cualquier imagen?
(Que el alto ocupe lo que necesite, pero que el ancho de la imagen se ajuste a todo el ancho del CardView)

La mayoría de imagenes me quedan como la foto 2 y no me sirve de esta forma.

Ya probe los [8 tipos de escalado de imagen](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide?fbclid=IwAR32Ao0jiQvu1TDaKCA9tJ3UIzv6kyDdtzfWtnZrjHE0FBsU5zaXeb5pEoM), y por si solo ninguno me proporciona el resultado deseado.

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:src="@drawable/imagen01"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />
```

CardView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/transparenterecycler"
    android:orientation="vertical"   
    android:id="@+id/CardViewNF">

<LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
      
        <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imgFeedAsync"
        android:tooltipText="@drawable/lalaland"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />

        <TextView
          android:text="Descripcion del contenido que va a ir en la parte inferior"
          android:id="@+id/txtContent"
          android:textSize="16sp"
          android:textColor="#000000"
          android:fontFamily="@font/quicks"
          android:textStyle="normal"
          android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Imagen 1 - Resultado deseado

[image: Imagen 1 - Resultado deseado]

Imagen 2 - Resultado actual

[image: Imagen 2 - Resultado actual]

Comment: Pon el xml del `cardview`

Comment: Listo @FranqoBalsamo

Comment: ¿Las imágenes son descargadas de internet o las tienes almacenadas en el drawable?

Comment: Son descargadas, esas que puse son de ejemplo del drawable.

Comment: Perfecto, ¿Puedes añadir el proyecto a `Git` y adjuntar el link? Me interesa más que nada la parte de los dos `xml` y la `activity` con los **archivos jpg/png**.

Comment: No podría, es un proyecto grande colaborativo que de momento tiene algunas API Keys visibles y no podría ponerme a quitar lo sensible, ni compartir todo el proyecto. Vere si le encuentro luego al problema, pero muy amable por la asistencia.

Comment: Te hago una consulta, ¿CUál es la diferencia entre los dos ImageView que has puesto? Es decir, veo que primero pones un ImageView y luego el layout del CardView, ¿Son los mismos?

Comment: No, es en el mismo CardView lo que pasa es que para explicarme busque una imagen que quedara tal cual la necesitaba; y en la imagen 1 la imagen es tan grande que no me alcanzo a recortar el TextView inferior que si sale en la otra imagen.

Comment: Para mi el problema es que la imagen tiene un tamaño muy pequeño. Intenta establecerle un alto y un ancho específicos.

Comment: Quería un resultado como el de Facebook (sin importar el tamaño de alto de la imagen, siempre se ajusta a todo el ancho de la pantalla), pero creo que al final lo que hare es poner una opción de "Recorte" antes de publicar la imagen para lograr una imagen cuadrada y así forzar el escalado con FitXY (un resultado similar al de Instagram); ya que no logro obtener el resultado deseado sin distorsionar la imagen.